# How to set static width for one column of gridview with dynamic datatable target?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm getting data from dynamic datatable and can't specify all columns.

When I set it for first column alike:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="dt" DataField="dt" 
        HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
</Columns>
```

I get double of this time after `DataBind`

Is there way I can make the same but without double-ing this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for fixing the column width of one of your columns, then you can do it in RowDataBound event:

```
private void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)) {

            // For setting the width of first column to 100px
            TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            cell.Width = new Unit("100px");

        }
    }
```